# Launch4j gives error message: "Java Virtual Machine Launcher: A Java Exception has occurred". Any idea why?

Tags: launch4j

First time poster at StackOverflow.
First time user of Launch4j.

I use Windows 11.
I started the GUI version (3.50) of Launch4j.
I tried to make as few changes as possible.
I ended up with the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>Robert.jar</jar>
  <outfile>Robert.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl></downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>Robert.ico</icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>com.robert_domain.robert_main</mainClass>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path>c:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8</path>
    <requiresJdk>false</requiresJdk>
    <requires64Bit>false</requires64Bit>
    <minVersion>1.8</minVersion>
   <maxVersion></maxVersion>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

It does create an exe, but when I double-click the exe, it gets the error in the subject line.

I posted to the Launch4j page at SourceForge.
My post is "awaiting moderation" for the past 3 days.
I emailed the host, but no response.

I'm at a loss. I have no idea what to do next.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Build it with "headerType" console and run from cmd, then you schould have more details from log.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up paying a consultant who figured it out for me.